# Why is Angular JS $http.get() not working in this code?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to get the RSS feeds from a link. The `ng-click` function `getNews("SomeText")` is working, I have confirmed it with filling a container with some text. However, `$http.get()` is not working. I only want to show the data for now, I'll parse it later.

Here is my Angular JS code.

```
var app = angular.module("app",[]);
app.controller("newsController", function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.getNews = function(topic) {

    if (topic === "NAmerica") {
    //The program enters this part, I have confirmed, only $http.get() doesn't work
      $http.get('http://www.usnews.com/rss/education')
      .then(function (response) {
        $scope.message = response;

      });
    }
  };
});
```

My HTML file has this structure:

```
<html ng-app="app">
   <body ng-controller="newsContainer">
       <a href="#" id="NAmerica" ng-click="getNews('NAmerica')">US &amp; Canada</a>
       <p> {{message}} </p>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does the response look like?  Is it just a string?  My guess is that an object is getting returned and you have to do something like `response.data`.

Comment: Your controller is called newsController, not newsContainer.

Comment: You can't just use AJAX on any URL. The server you are hitting has to allow it. As it is, the one you are attempting, does not. `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.usnews.com/rss/education?_=1449166602671. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'` Edit: Also, typo on controller name, as mentioned above.

Comment: @JanKlimo, I have corrected that mistake, still doesn't work.

Comment: @R.Salisbury No response whatsoever.

Comment: @Antiga How else can I get it working?

Comment: `http://www.usnews.com/rss/education` is not a Restful API. If you try to do a `get` request on Postman, it returns you some XML stuff.

Comment: what about putting an iframe in your site ?

Comment: @Ro. I don't want to use an iframe because I want to display the data in a specific format. I have got the answer by the way, i.e. there's no way to request data from a different server (from within client browser) because of Same-Origin Policy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already noted in comments, modern browsers cannot simply request arbitrary URLs via AJAX. This restriction is entirely intentional and called the [Same-Origin Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). By default, browsers can only execute AJAX requests to the same domain that the JavaScript is executed on.

Usually, there are a few options that you can take.

1. Cross-Domain requests are allowed when the requested site contains a *Cross-Origin Resource Sharing* (CORS) header in its HTTP response, which usually looks something like this:

   ```
   Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://yoursite.com
   ```

   Of course, this is only an option when you're in control of the domain that you're requesting content from. If you're executing requests to a 3rd party site, there's usually nothing that you can do about this on your own.

   Btw, you should also be able to see a respective error message in your browser console.
2. Request the foreign content using a server-side script on your domain, for instance using a PHP or *[insert random server-side scripting language here]* script on *your* server that you then request via AJAX. That way, you can work around the Same-Origin Policy, since the user's browser can now request a resource on your own domain.

Comment: I didn't know about Same-Origin Policy. So you suggest, I should rather request my server to run a script that gets the response and forward it to client?